# docker: possible to create a single file with binaries and packages installed?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

Basically I want to create a "snapshot" of my current Ubuntu box, which has compiled binaries and various apt-get packages installed on it. I want to create a docker instance of this as a file that I can distribute to my AWS ec2 instances which will be stored on S3 bucket that will be mounted by the ec2.

Is it possible to achieve this, and how do you get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to take a snapshot of a current box and use it as a docker container, but you can certainly create a container to use on your EC2 instances.

1. Create a [Dockerfile](http://docs.docker.io/reference/builder/) that builds the system exactly as you want it.
2. Once you've created the perfect Dockerfile, [export a container to a tarball](http://docs.docker.io/reference/commandline/cli/#export)
3. Upload the tarball to S3
4. On your EC2 instances, download the tarball and [import it as a Docker container](http://docs.docker.io/reference/commandline/cli/#import).

Are you planning to use something like s3fs to mount an S3 bucket? Otherwise you can just copy the tarball from your bucket either as a userdata boot script or during a chef/puppet/ansible provisioning step. Depends how you want to structure it.

Comment: does it take a long time for the dockerfile to setup the environment on the instance? I am planning to use s3 bucket. Basically, I thought it would work like, mount the docker image, have all my binaries and packages readily accessible without having to run a long script to compile and install every little package which would take several minutes.

Comment: You will use your Dockerfile to build the image one time. When you use `docker export` the image is saved as a tarball, then turned back in to a docker image when you import it on the EC2 instance. It will have all the packages and other steps that you had in the Dockerfile.